# React - Element type is invalid - how to debug this error?

Tags: reactjs

How can this error message given by react debugged ? To figure out what is really causing it ? I googled the error but it seems to be caused by different things.

`invariant.js:38 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

given by this code:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore , combineReducers} from 'redux'
import deepFreeze from 'deepfreeze'
import expect from 'expect'
var _ = require('lodash')

type State$Todo = {
  text:string;
  completed:boolean;
  id:number;
};

class Todo {
  static make(t:string,id:number):State$Todo{
    return {text:t,id:id,completed:false}
  }
  static toggle(t:State$Todo):State$Todo {
    return {...t, completed:!t.completed};
  }
};

type Action$SetVisibilityFilter = {
     type:'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER',
     filter:State$VisibilityFilter
};

type Action$ADD_TODO = {
  type:'ADD_TODO',
  text:string,
  id:number
};

type Action$TOGGLE_TODO = { type:'TOGGLE_TODO', id:number }

type Action$Todo = Action$ADD_TODO | Action$TOGGLE_TODO

type Action$App = Action$Todo | Action$SetVisibilityFilter

type State$TodoList = State$Todo[];

type State$VisibilityFilter = 'SHOW_ACTIVE' | 'SHOW_ALL' | 'SHOW_COMPLETED'

type State$App = {
  todos:State$TodoList,
  visibilityFilter:State$VisibilityFilter
}

const todosReducer = (state: State$TodoList=[], action: Action$App) :State$TodoList=>{
      switch (action.type){
        case 'ADD_TODO' : return [ ... state, Todo.make(action.text, action.id)];
        case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
          const id=action.id;
          return  _.map(state, (td) => (td.id==id) ? Todo.toggle(td) : td );
        default : return state;
      }
};

const visibilityFilterReducer = (state:State$VisibilityFilter = 'SHOW_ALL', action:Action$App) : State$VisibilityFilter =>  {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
      return action.filter;
    default : return state;
  }
}

const todoApp = (state : State$App = {todos:[],visibilityFilter:'SHOW_ALL'}, action: Action$App) : State$App => {
  return { todos: todosReducer(state.todos, action), visibilityFilter: visibilityFilterReducer(state.visibilityFilter,action) };
}

//const todoApp =combineReducers({todos:todosReducer, visibilityFilter:visibilityFilterReducer})
const store  = createStore (todoApp)



type FilterLinkProps={
  filter:State$VisibilityFilter,
  currentFilter:State$VisibilityFilter,
  children:React$Element<*>
};

const FilterLink = ({
  filter,
  currentFilter,
  children
}:FilterLinkProps) => {
  if(filter===currentFilter) {
    return <span>{children}</span>
  }
  return (
    <a href='#'
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        store.dispatch(({
          type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER',
          filter
        }:Action$SetVisibilityFilter));
      }}
    >
    {children}
    </a>
  );
};

const getVisibleTodos = (
  todos:State$TodoList,
  filter:State$VisibilityFilter
) : State$TodoList => {
  switch (filter) {
    case ('SHOW_ALL' :State$VisibilityFilter):
      return todos;
    case ('SHOW_COMPLETED':State$VisibilityFilter):
      return todos.filter(
        t => t.completed
      );
    case ('SHOW_ACTIVE':State$VisibilityFilter):
      return todos.filter(
        t => !t.completed
      );
    default:
      throw "undefined action"
  }
}

let nextTodoId = 0;
const TodoReactElement=(props:{onClick:Function,completed:boolean,text:string}) =>(
            <li onClick={props.onClick}
                style ={{ textDecoration: props.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}} >
                {props.text}
            </li>
);

type TodoListReactComponentProps ={todos:State$TodoList,onTodoClick:Function}

const TodoList =(props:TodoListReactComponentProps) =>(
  <ul>
    {props.todos.map( todo=>
      <TodoReactElement
        key ={todo.id}
        completed={todo.completed}
        onClick={()=> props.onTodoClick(todo.id)}
        text= {todo.text} >
      </TodoReactElement>)}
  </ul>
)


class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const todos : State$TodoList= this.props.todos;
    const visibilityFilter :State$VisibilityFilter=
          this.props.visibilityFilter;
    const visibleTodos :State$TodoList = getVisibleTodos(
      todos, visibilityFilter );

    return (
      <div>
      <input ref ={ node => {this.input=node;} } />
        <button onClick={() => {
          store.dispatch(({
            type: 'ADD_TODO',
            text: 'Test'+this.input.value,
            id: nextTodoId++
          } : Action$ADD_TODO));
          this.input.value='';
        }}>
          Add Todo
        </button>
        <TodoList todos={visibleTodos}
                  onTodoClick={id=> store.dispatch(({type:'TOGGLE_TODO',id}:Action$TOGGLE_TODO))}>
        </TodoList>
        <p>
          Show:
          {' '}
          <FilterLink
            filter='SHOW_ALL'
            currentFilter={visibilityFilter}
          >
          All
          </FilterLink>
          {' '}
          <FilterLink
            filter='SHOW_ACTIVE'
            currentFilter={visibilityFilter}
          >
          Active
          </FilterLink>
          {' '}
          <FilterLink
            filter='SHOW_COMPLETED'
            currentFilter={visibilityFilter}
          >
          Completed
          </FilterLink>
        </p>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
const root   = document.getElementById('root')
const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <TodoApp {...store.getState()} />,root
  );
};

store.subscribe(render)
render();
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: that is in `invariant.js`, not in my code - as can be seen from the screenshot

Comment: Was it `{props.text}`? Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I only speak Javascript, not Typescript (or whatever that was), but the error itself is pretty clear: you tried to render something (an object) that React wasn't expecting (because it expects strings/functions).

I see two possibilities:

1) there is a bug in `invariant.js`; since the error came from there this could be the problem, but more likely ...

2) one of your render methods includes (in its `return` value) an object

Unfortunately, as you've discovered, React stack traces are not always particularly helpful.  Personally I would recommend just commenting out the `render` methods of your classes, one at a time, starting with the outermost one (which I *think* is `FilterLink` in your case), and replace them temporarily with a simple `return <div/>`.

Then try to produce the error again.  If you still get it, restore the `render` method and go do the same thing to the next class up the component chain.  If not, you've found your problematic `render`.  If you can't immediately see the problem by looking at it, try logging every variable involved in it (or, if you use Lodash/Underscore, `_.isObject(thatVariable)`) until you find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is quite straight forward, but in what component? That's the question.
Actually, in the callstack, there are some points has some parent components.

Add a break point at such as `instantiateReactComponent (instantiateReactComponent.js:74)` and retry.
Clicking `mountComponent   ...reactConciler.js...` will lead you to calling `internalInstance.mountComponent`. and in the internalInstance, you can find some meaningful element type in `_currentElement.type`.
There you could find the child with invalid type.

[image: _currentElement.type]

Answer (score 0):

You've specified here that FilterLink's "children" prop only accepts React elements:

```
type FilterLinkProps={
  // ... snipped ...
  children:React$Element<*>
};
```

...but you are passing non-React elements (objects, strings, etc).  You need change prop type to "React.PropTypes.node" instead of "React.PropTypes.element"  (sorry I don't speak that syntax either, but I can see what's going on, basically)

Answer (score 0):

If someone could not relate his/her issue with other answers, this might be because of non-imported components. I had instantiated component and saved as element in a variable and used it in render function of another component.

```js
//mainComp.tsx
const icon = <SomeIcon/>

return <div>{icon}</div>

* Did not get any error that SomeIcon is not imported. while trying to render this element type will be undefined.
```